# Midi editor/composer for Linux

Tags: linux, unix, debian, music, midi

I need to compose midi music in Linux.
I have experience this on Windows. There are lots of software out there for Windows that could do this.
But now that I have switch to Linux (Debian, in particular), I would like to know what will be the software for this. 
Thanks in advance.
(I don't care if it's on command line or GUI)

Comment: What have you already found and tried?

Comment: @slhck I have tried softwares on Windows. But I was looking for Linux counter part so I won't anymore switch to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compose music and output it to MIDI format, MuseScore is cross-platform:

http://musescore.org/en